# Is there any Revolver / Sniper Build for Borderland's Siren?

Tags: borderlands

I am currently playing a Siren in borderlands, and i was wondering, if there is any "drawback" of playing it as a Sniper / Revolver character ?

I am a fan of Sniper rifles and Revolvers, but i already have one Mordecai in my "party" (co-op).

After looking for a while, i could not find anything that makes Siren better with a SMG than the other characters, so teorically, i could make it use any weapon without further losses, right ?

I Know i should avoid these sort of question here, but, which is the "Best" Build for her ? I mean, is there any tree that is really better than the others ?

Here is the build calculator for her : [Calculator](http://www.borderlandsthegame.com/skilltree/lilith/#20000000000000000000000)

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: I am a fan of Sniper rifles and Revolvers, but i already have one Mordecai in my "party" (co-op).

Comment: fwiw I really like my [lilith build](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/60832/3917).  While she doesn't have any skills that boost SMGS in particular, she has skills that trigger as a chance per shot (like Daze), rapid shooting weapons really benefit her more, hence SMGs are better overall.

Comment: @YX rapid shotting or more bullets.
So in theory, either smgs or shotguns would do great with lilith.

Comment: yes that's right, shotguns wouldn't be bad either, but they're even worse than SMGs at range

Comment: If you have the Knoxx DLC there's a sniper COM for Siren. Revolvers work fine for her. Also the Orion sniper rifle is pretty sick with Lillith, though you'll run out of ammo fast.

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins Shotguns are meh for lillith, you'll get some better elemental effects out of them but shotguns have relatively poor elemental effects. I'd recommend a fast shooting one like the explosive Crux for close combat...but they still hurt less than good SMGs. Nothing beats an Anarchy or Hellfire for ripping people up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skills aside, all of the characters have the potential to be equally proficient with all weapons.  The difference comes in when you assign skill points; Mordecai has many skills that only affect sniper rifles and revolvers, Brick has rocket launcher skills, Roland has assault rifle and shotgun skills... and Lilith doesn't have any skills affected purely by weapon type.

What she *does* have, though, are skills that have effects per bullet, that have elemental effects, and that increase her firing rate.  Obviously fire rate increases are less beneficial with snipers and revolvers, and 'per bullet' and elemental effects proc more often using weapons with faster fire rates-- i.e. SMGs.  The intention with Lilith was clearly that she should be an SMG user, but really, you can do whatever you want if it works for you!

That being said, if you really want to play with snipers and revolvers, you might want to fight your friend for Mordecai-- he is definitely the best sniper user.  Roland might also be a better choice, since his skills tend to be more generally applicable to all weapon types, and focussed on support.

Of course you can also just keep multiple weapon types with you, and switch between them as the situation requires!

In short, there *are* slight drawbacks to using a weapon type your character wasn't really 'made' for, but they're not so significant that they'll ruin your experience.  My advice is to just play with what you find the most fun-- there's always time to re-spec, re-gear and train your proficiency with another weapon later!

EDIT:  Some notes on building Lilith:
If I recall my studies of elemental effects correctly (please someone correct me if I'm wrong), the weapons that benefit the most from elemental effects are actually rocket launchers, followed by snipers.  SMGs will get their effects more often in general due to their fast firerate, but snipers will get better/ more effects per bullet fired.  I'd recommend a mostly Assassin build, namely Spark, Slayer, Enforcer, and High Velocity: increased bullet speed and accuracy, high crit damage, and good elemental chance.

Comment: Hey, Jesse, thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, you're not addressing the question at all; the question is "Is there any revolver/sniper builds for the siren?", and your answer is just "Use Mordecai".

Comment: I Disagree fbueckert, he answered my question.

Comment: Fair enough, then!

Comment: Glad you like the answer Marcello!  fbueckert, you are right in fact; I didn't mention any explicit builds.  Unfortunately I can't really help in that regard, not being familiar with Lilith, though looking at her skill tree I can make some recommendations.  I'll edit the answer just to include my ruminations.

Answer (score 2):

Siren has the best proficiency with SMGs and elemental weapons. If you really want to go for snipers and/or handguns I suggest you to follow her elemental tree and use elemental sniper rifles/handguns. Use her character skill to escape from incoming melee enemies when using the sniper rifle or to confuse them when using the revolver.

This is probably the best way to use your preferred weapons, because in no tree there are bonuses for sniper rifles or handguns only, so try to focus on elemental weapons.

Have fun with that cool lady!

Comment: What you mean with better proficiency?
She have the same proficiency as every other character.
Thanks for the rest of the info tho

Comment: I meant [this](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_proficiency) but I thought tables were different for every character. My bad.

Comment: np, i just edited your answer to make it right now.